# Getting parent_id for nested children

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to JPA and I'm stumped on how to capture the parent id param for nested children. I have two entities, Data and Property. Right now I successfully managed to create a one to many mapping from Data to Property. The thing is that Property can have its own children of itself. The "first layer" properties are able to get and save the data id value, but properties nested in another property are unable to do so. I was wondering if there is a method to do something like this since I could not find any information on it online.

**Data (parent class)**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "data")
public class Data implements Serializable {
    // omitted non relevant code

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = EventProperty.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "data_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<EventProperty> properties;
}
```

**Property (child class)**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "property")
public class Property implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1100374255977700675L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "data_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private EventData eventData;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private EventProperty parent;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = EventProperty.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<EventProperty> children;
}
```

I'm wondering if storing the properties as a List in Data is the right way to go, or if there's any way to set data_id of a child Property to be the same as the parent Property if it is null, or if there's some other correct way that I am not aware of. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what exactly is the issue you are facing? I got your data model, if you can put some example data with what is saved and what is the data not getting associated it will be clear

Comment: And how exactly are you saving your data, if you can add those method calls it would make sense

Comment: The data_id field in the child class is null if the child class is within another child class. I'm saving my data using dataRepository(data), where data is a Data object. Thank you!

Comment: you need set those fields framework will not do it.
have you set data_id of child of child?

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I'm not sure about, how to get and set the data_id of a child of child, since the framework handled the "first layer" of children by itself.

Comment: you have to set the  private EventData eventData; field to the parent data you want before calling save()

Comment: I tried setting the field of the parent data before calling save(), but unfortunately it resulted in a recursive loop between the data and property.

Comment: Fixed, thank you so much for your suggestion! I used @JsonIgnore to prevent infinite recursion.